# Using Ansible inside Bash

Tags: bash, debian, apache-httpd, php, ansible

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with Ansible installed this way:

```
apt-get update -y
install software-properties-common
apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
apt install ansible
```

I also have a small Bash script I store in GitHub that I sometimes copy-paste into the terminal of remote machines I hire to store my own websites on (as for now I plan to have only one such remote machine, not tens/hundreds or thousands as common for most Ansible users).

### The script

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update -y
apt-get install lamp-server^
apt-get install php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-curl php-cli php-gd
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

One could say "well, if it's just one machine don't use Ansible at all, it would be an overkill" but I still feel the need to automate this as it is a very "messy" installation command set that might change "tomorrow".

### My problem

I don't find literature to explain how I could do the same installations, inside the Bash terminal (say from copy-pasting the command set) **but with Ansible**. I also bought a printed version of Jeff Geerling's book "Ansible for Devops" but none of the basic chapters covers my particular need.

All I find is how to deploy a playbook file to a list of IPs but I don't want to use this "traditional" way for Ansible. I just want to copy a Ansible YAML command set from GitHub to my terminal.

### My question

Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the playbook file to the new host and play it to the local host using the following yaml directives:

- `hosts: 127.0.0.1`: The `localhost` address [for nearly any machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).
- `connection: local`: A yaml direction for the type of connection; given we work locally in this case, it's conceptually useless, but it's technically necessary due to how the current version of Ansible is built).

See [here](https://www.tricksofthetrades.net/2017/10/02/ansible-local-playbooks/) for the gory details.

Answer (score 4):

From the Ansible Docs:

```
    - name: Install a list of packages
apt:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
vars:
    packages:
    - foo
    - foo-tools

    - name: Download foo.conf
get_url:
    url: http://example.com/path/file.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    mode: 0440
```

Since this is written in Ansible Playbook format. You would need to write it to a yaml file, and then you can call the playbook from your script. You would not be able to embed the yaml file in a bash script and then call it within the script.